# i am getting blank chart after setting plt.ylim

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sn
data= pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\AmitSatappa\Desktop\praticalone\netflix_titles.csv',encoding='cp1252')
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
duplicate= data[data.duplicated()]
data.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)   
new_data= data[data.duplicated()]
nullvalue = data.isnull()
plt.ylim(1,3000)
sn.barplot(nullvalue)
plt.show()
```

[before setting the plt.ylim i was getting the graph but after setting the limit i am geeting it as blank only[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoVX9.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPHxz.png)

Comment: The y_lim() is set to show numbers between 1 and 3000, while the max bar (title) is only ~0.3, which is less than 1. So, change it to something like `plt.ylim(0,0.5)`

Comment: Image links are not preferred, please just upload the image